# how to Replace an Integer with string 20 percent of the time Clojure

Tags: clojure, integer, lisp

I need to replace an integer with a string in clojure but only for 20% of the outputted integers.

```
(defn factor5 [x]
  (if (= (mod x 3) (mod x 5) 0) "BuzzFizz"
  (if (= (mod x 5) 0) "buzz"
  (if (= (mod x 3) 0) "fizz" x))))
```

here i have a fizzbuzz program which prints out "fizz" if the number is a multiple of 3 or "buzz" if it is a multiple of 5 and "BuzzFizz" is printed if is a multiple of both. if an integer is neither of the above multiplies the integer gets printed. What i need is to print "Boom" instead of the integer but only for 20% of the integers.

some pseudo code

```
 if(x == int){
   print out Boom instead of x only for 20% }
   else{
   print out x}
```

I have very limited exprience in clojure as my pseudocode is java based

Comment: do you want that 20% to be random?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [the Clojure Cheatsheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) for a comprehensive listing of functions.

The one you want is `rand`, and a test like:

```
(if (< (rand) 0.2) ....)
```

Comment: Thanks guys I've not got a reputation of 15 so I can't upvote but many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the decision made randomly you could use one of the rand runctions in an if statement like so:

```
user> (defn x20% [x]
        (if (rand-nth [true false false false false])
          "Boom"
          x))
#'user/x20%
user> (x20% 5)
5
user> (x20% 5)
5
user> (x20% 5)
"Boom"
user> (x20% 5)
5
```

there are also `rand` and `rand-int`. which you use is somewhat a matter of style and the specifics of your function:

```
user> (> 2 (rand-int 10))
true
user> (> 2 (rand-int 10))
true
user> (> 2 (rand-int 10))
false
user> (> 0.2 (rand))
true
user> (> 0.2 (rand))
```

Comment: I think your `<` test is backward...?

Comment: yep, exactly backwards, thanks for keeping me honest!

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn factor-5 [x]
  (if (and (number? x) (zero? (rem x 1)))
    (if (zero? (rand-int 5))
      "Boom"
      x)))
```

- This returns the required value rather than printing it.
- It tests that its argument is numeric, and - if so - that it is a
  whole number value, which could be `byte`, `short`, `int`, ... .
- `(rand-int 5)` chooses randomly from `0, 1, ... 4`.